# p5js, need help using get() to detect the color of a pixel as a RGBA array to see if the mouse is hovering over it

Tags: p5.js

Currently learning and working on a project, for this particular case I'm trying to simulate a collision detection by obtaining the color of a pixel with get().
In the console log, I can see the color array of the pixel the mouse is hovering on corresponds to my color in the colors array but then I can't seem to compare them. Seems like I'm unable to see through some basic principle, I've been trying for some hours to find a solution to no avail.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
colors = [[255, 165, 0, 255], [61, 145, 64, 255], [204, 0, 0, 255], [31, 117, 254, 255], 
    [160, 32, 240, 255], [0, 128, 128, 255], [244, 0, 161, 255]];
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    fill(colors[i]);
    ellipse(120, 40 + 45 * i, 40);
    
  let c = get(mouseX, mouseY);
  // console.log(c);
  if(c == colors[i]){
    console.log(colors[i]);
  }
  
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function I added at the bottom.

```
function setup() {
    

createCanvas(400, 400);
  
colors = [[255, 165, 0, 255], [61, 145, 64, 255], [204, 0, 0, 255], [31, 117, 254, 255], 
    [160, 32, 240, 255], [0, 128, 128, 255], [244, 0, 161, 255]];
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    fill(colors[i]);
    ellipse(120, 40 + 45 * i, 40);
    
    
  }
  for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
  let c = get(mouseX, mouseY);
  
  if(arrayEquals(c,colors[i])){
    console.log(colors[i]);
  }
  }

}

function arrayEquals(a, b) { //define a function with arguments a,b
  return Array.isArray(a) && //true if 'a' is an array, '&&' checks if all arguments are true to return true otherswise false
    Array.isArray(b) && //true if 'b' is an array
    a.length === b.length && //true if 'a' is the same length as 'b'
    a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]); //true if 'a' value is the same as the 'b' value at the same position for all positions
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the name of the coding techniques used?
This is amazing btw.

Comment: What do you mean by name? as in making your own function?

Comment: "ArrayEquals" *is* the technique. My apologies, I thought it was just a name you gave to the function. Thank you for your getting back to me

Comment: I annotated above to explain what the points inside the function do.